# Convert Text to Date field

Tags: date, field-update

How do you populate a text field yyyy-mm into a date field setting the day as 01 as mm/01/yyyy?

Comment: Hi @jellybean, are you doing this through apex? Can you add some tags and show some of your work so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of your dates will be in `yyyy-mm` format.

If you're doing this in a Field Update the following formula should work.

```
DATE(VALUE(LEFT(TextField__c, 4)), VALUE(RIGHT(TextField__c, 2)), 1)
```

In Apex you could use the following:

```
String dateString = '2014-09';
Integer year = Integer.valueOf(dateString.subString(0, 4));
Integer month = Integer.valueOf(dateString.subString(5));
Date d = Date.newInstance(year, month, 1);
```

You could also look into using `Date.parse(String)` or `Date.valueOf(String)`, but both those methods are a bit of a pain to use.

- [Date.parse(String) Documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_parse)
- [Date.valueOf(String)  Documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_valueOf)